# how to do a compound query in pfquerytableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, parse-platform, pfquery

I am using the delegate query for table method in my pfquerytableviewcontroller like so:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    return [self getMyQuery];
}

- (PFQuery *) getMyQuery{
    PFQuery *query = [FollowerRelation query];
    [query whereKey:@"follower" equalTo:user];

    NSArray *foundFollowers = [query findObjects];
    NSMutableArray *followers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (FollowerRelation *aFollower in foundFollowers) {
        [followers addObject:aFollower.user];
    }

    PFQuery *query1 = [GAStatus query];
    [query1 whereKey:@"user" containedIn:followers];
    [query1 includeKey:@"user"];
    [query1 orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    return query1;

}
```

When I do a simple query like:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query includeKey:@"gaUser"];
    if (self.objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;
}
```

It works with no problem.  How do I use my query that first selects all users?

Comment: Please elaborate more on what the problem is. What is happening when you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand the question fully, so if I'm wrong please correct me. Why can't you just put this code in queryForTable?

PFQuery *query = [FollowerRelation query];
    [query whereKey:@"follower" equalTo:user];

```
NSArray *foundFollowers = [query findObjects];
NSMutableArray *followers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (FollowerRelation *aFollower in foundFollowers) {
    [followers addObject:aFollower.user];
}

PFQuery *query1 = [GAStatus query];
[query1 whereKey:@"user" containedIn:followers];
[query1 includeKey:@"user"];
[query1 orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

return query1;
```

Exactly what query do you want to accomplish/return for the table?

Comment: That is essentially what I did, but extracted out to another method.  I think since there is latency on this call in the main thread, the method shuts down.

Comment: So the issue is that the query is not executing correctly?

Comment: Before I switched to the pfquerytableviewcontroller, this identical query worked no problem.

Comment: Does it crash or just take a while to load?